# how to give files as links to servlet in anchor tag

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

I'm writing a servlet code to display files in the datbase and am trying to give file name as link in anchor tag but it shows error!.. some help please!, here's my code:

```
out.println("<body>");
out.println("<h1>Download list </h1>"); 
out.println("<table>");
while(rs.next()) {
    String ns=rs.getString("uname");
    out.println("<tr><td>File Name:</td>");
    out.println("<td><a href="/Download">"+ns+"</td></tr>");
    out.println("</table>");
} 
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

Comment: what error are you getting? is it downloading error?

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
out.println("<td><a href='/download'>" + ns + "</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

we assume that,

your servlet url-pattern entry in web.xml is "/Download"

If you want to download a file with a parameter as file name, you should try something like -

```
    out.println("<tr><td>File Name:</td>");
    out.println("<td><a href="/Download?filename="+ns+">"+ns+"</td></tr>");
```

and then you should write the code for download functionality in the Servlet for the requested parameter - filename

Please elaborate us your error, so that we can help you in right direction to solve your problem.

Thanks